# Display Image from dataBase to ListView ( with AsyncTask )

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, android-asynctask, imageview

I want to set an image to an ImageView inside a ListView correctly. I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter to display all the fields and using a ViewBinder to set the image bitmap to the ImageView. The image is downloaded using an AsyncTask . But the image is not on the correct row.

```
mCurAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {


            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (view.getId()==R.id.iconPosition) {
                    Log.d("COLONNE INDEX",""+columnIndex);

                    ImageView image = (ImageView) view;



                        new DownloadImage(image).execute(cursor.getInt(columnIndex));

                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
            this.setListAdapter(mCurAdapter);

         return view;
        }
```

DownloadImage  AsyncTask

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Bitmap>{

            private ImageView imv;

            public DownloadImage(ImageView image){
                imv=image;
            }
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return downloadImage(arg0[0]);
            }


            protected void onPostExecute (Bitmap image) {

                if(image != null && imv != null){

                    imv.setImageBitmap(image);}

            }

            private Bitmap downloadImage(Integer res) {

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize=8;
                Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),res,options);

                return bitmap;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that the recycling is messing up with your views.
I am just guessing here.
Try to tag your view.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) view;
image.setTag("row2");
```

And use getTag() to identify your imageview.

```
        protected void onPostExecute (Bitmap image) {

            if(image != null && imv != null && imv.gettag().equals("row2")){

                imv.setImageBitmap(image);}

        }
```

If the above doesnt try [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) which is very efficient.

Comment: It's not working, the image change when i navigate in the listView. But when i not use Asynctask, it is working

Comment: You are facing recycling problem, try lazylist https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: LazyList use URL and BaseAdapter but me, I use drawable and SimpleCursorAdapter, so i can't use LazyList

Comment: I changed my application to retrieve the image from an url and it's worked. Thanks Lazy Ninja :)